# Часть речи

Tags: морфология

Какой морфемой (частью слова) следует считать "СУ" в следующих примерах:

**суглинок, сумрак, сустав, сутолока, судно** и т.п.?

Comment: Спасибо!
А СУДНО не имеет ли отношение к русс.ДНО ?
В таком случае здесь так же стоит приставка СУ: СУ+ДНО.

Comment: почти глина, почти мрак, сурепка-почти репка, почти (устаревшее) став(ныне без приставок не используется) аналог состав(в качестве примера-ставок, ставить, ставни).  Приставка су немного не дотягивает до объединяющего значения приставки со: содружество, сопротивление, соображение.
некоторые корни слов с этой приставкой ныне выглядят архаично из-за изменений в написании и звучании.  например судно, к дну по видимому не имеют отношения, 
некоторые сравнивают с посудой, посудина. есть подозрение, что связано со временем изготовления, суденышко, за один день строится. в том числе и сама посуда.

Answer (score 3):

Непродуктивной приставкой. Кроме судна, мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Приставка СУ в современном языке определяется словарем как нерегулярная приставка со значением преобладания того, что названо мотивирующим существительным: мрак - сумрак, глина - суглинок.

В других случаях СУ является вариантом СО: судорога,  сугубый (согнутый), супруг, супостат, сутки (соткнуться), сутолока (сотолкаться), совать - сунуть.

Судно - от др.-рус. судъ со значением "вместилище", Н - суффикс, родственные слова судок, сосуд, посуда.